# Why need to add 2 private var in this person Class?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am new in Ios programming in swift 3. I am curious about why need to create private VAR in getter and setter inside a Class ? And what will happen if I dont add these 2 private ( var )?

```
class Person { 
    private var _firstname: String!
    private var _lastname: String!

    var firstname: String { 
        return _firstname 
    }

    var lastname: String { 
        return _lastname 
    } 

    var fullname: String { 
        return "\(firstname) \(lastname)"
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have shown is using the private backing variables to provide read-only properties implemented through computed variables. There is no setter and no getter.

Presumably, `_firstname` and `_lastname` are set in an initializer that isn't shown. Once the private variables are set, they cannot be changed by any public methods.

If you were happy for a `Person` instance to have its name changed at any point, then you could use simple public `String` variables instead of the backing variables and computed properties.

Answer (score 3):

That private stored property with exposed get-only computed property is a pattern designed to make the variable public, but keeping the setter private. A more concise way of accomplishing this would be to specify a private setter for the stored property, eliminating the need for those computed properties:

```
class Person { 
    private(set) var firstname: String!
    private(set) var lastname: String!

    var fullname: String { 
        return "\(firstname ?? "") \(lastname ?? "")"
    } 
}
```

Note, if you've defined these to be implicitly unwrapped, then your `fullname` computed property might want to safely unwrap them, like above.

Or if the names cannot change, you might define them to be constants that are set by the initializer and never changed again:

```
struct Person {
    let firstname: String!
    let lastname: String!

    var fullname: String {
        return "\(firstname ?? "") \(lastname ?? "")"
    }
}
```

---

Completely unrelated, I'm not sure I'd advise implicitly wrapped optionals in this situation. The intent of implicitly unwrapped optionals is for properties that couldn't be set in the initializer, but once they're set, they're never `nil`.

Often when dealing with contacts, though, you have to contemplate the situation where they might be `nil`. In that case I wouldn't make them implicitly unwrapped optionals (e.g., I might use `?` rather than `!`). Or, if they couldn't be `nil`, I'd make sure to set them in the initializer, and then not make them optional at all. It all depends upon the business rules that you're going to capture with this definition. I'm going to assume you had a good reason to make these implicitly unwrapped optionals, but for the sake of future readers, I'd only warn that one should be wary of using implicitly unwrapped optionals too casually.

Answer (score 1):

1. This is not swift 3.0. This is swift 2.3.
2. You don't have to. Example where var variable doesn't have "private (var)":

   ```
   class Person {
       private var variable: String = "" // you need to initialize it
       private var _variable2: String?

       var variable2: String {
           get {
               return _variable2 ?? "no value" // returns value or "no value" string
           }
           set {
               self._variable2 = newValue
           }
       }


   }
   ```